# Why do my JSON Results pass the schema validation on NewtonSoft site's validator but not in AnyPoint API Designer?

Tags: json, jsonschema, raml

I have this schema:

```
  {
   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "type" : "object",
   "properties": {
     "competingApplications": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "isFunded": {
                   "type": "boolean"
                },
                "councilRound": {
                   "type": ["string", "null"],
                   "description": "a number represented by a string"
                },
                "esiNewInvestigatorFlag": {
                   "type": "string"
                },
                "applStatusGroup": {
                   "type": "string"
                },
                "foaNumber": {
                   "type": ["string", "null"],
                   "description": "a number represented by a string"
                },
                "pcc": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                },
                "priorityScore": {
                    "type": ["integer", "null"]
                },
                "percentile": {
                  "type": ["number", "null"]
                },
                "orgName": {
                   "type": "string"
                },
                "studySection": {
                   "type": "string"
                },
                "directCost": {
                   "type": ["number", "null"]
                },
                "totalCost": {
                   "type": ["number", "null"]
                },
                "totalCount": {
                   "type": "integer"
                },
                "applId": { 
                   "type": "integer" 
                },
                "fullApplNum": { 
                    "type": "string" 
                },
                "projectTitle": { 
                    "type": "string" 
                },   
                "fiscalYear": { 
                    "type": ["integer", "null"]
                },
                "contactPiProfilePersonId": { 
                    "type": ["integer", "null"]
                },
                "piNameList": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                },
                "adminPdProfilePersonId": {
                  "type": ["integer", "null"]
                },
                "pdNameList": {
                   "type": ["string", "null"]
                },
                "adminSroProfilePersonId": {
                  "type": ["integer", "null"]
                },
                "sroNameList": {
                  "type": ["string", "null"]
                },
                "adminGmoProfilePersonId": {
                  "type": ["integer", "null"]
                },
                "gmoNameList": {
                  "type": ["string", "null"]
                },
                "adminGmsProfilePersonId": {
                  "type": ["integer", "null"]
                },
                "gmsNameList": {
                  "type": ["string", "null"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "competingApplsFiscalData": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "year": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "description": "A Fiscal Year represented as a string."
                },
                "isFunded": {
                   "type": "integer",
                   "description": "A count of Funded Appls for the Fiscal Year."
                },
                "notFunded": {
                   "type": "integer",
                   "description": "A count of Un-Funded Appls for the Fiscal Year."
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And I have this JSON Response example:

```
{
  "competingApplications": [
    {
      "isFunded": true,
      "councilRound": "201610",
      "esiNewInvestigatorFlag": "N/A",
      "applStatusGroup": "Awarded",
      "foaNumber": "PAR-16-106",
      "pcc": "CML14",
      "priorityScore": 27,
      "percentile": 12,
      "orgName": "UNIVERSITY OF CALIFORNIA AT DAVIS",
      "studySection": "ZHD1 DRG-D (80)",
      "directCost": 125000,
      "totalCost": 193000,
      "totalCount": 296,
      "applId": 9264724,
      "fullApplNum": "1R21OD023716-01",
      "projectTitle": "Leveraging Established Fetal Primate Models to     Expedite ZIKV Investigations",
      "fiscalYear": 2016,
      "contactPiProfilePersonId": 1867958,
      "piNameList": "TARANTAL, ALICE F;BARRY, PETER A;NOCTOR, STEPHEN     CHARLES",
      "adminPdProfilePersonId": 1941731,
      "pdNameList": "MORO, MANUEL H;CHAKHTOURA, NAHIDA ABDO",
      "adminSroProfilePersonId": 2435075,
      "sroNameList": "DUPERE, SHERRY L.",
      "adminGmoProfilePersonId": 6687597,
      "gmoNameList": "WILKOM, GAVIN",
      "adminGmsProfilePersonId": 14230024,
      "gmsNameList": "EATMON, ARTISHA"
    },
    {
      "isFunded": true,
      "councilRound": "201605",
      "esiNewInvestigatorFlag": "N/A",
      "applStatusGroup": "Awarded",
      "foaNumber": "PAR-13-253",
      "pcc": "CMM02",
      "priorityScore": 19,
      "percentile": null,
      "orgName": "BAYLOR COLLEGE OF MEDICINE",
      "studySection": "ZRG1 BBBP-Y (45)",
      "directCost": 586947,
      "totalCost": 718693,
      "totalCount": 296,
      "applId": 9147714,
      "fullApplNum": "1R24OD022005-01",
      "projectTitle": "A Comprehensive Human cDNA Library For Functional Gene Replacement in Drosophila",
      "fiscalYear": 2016,
      "contactPiProfilePersonId": 1887623,
      "piNameList": "BELLEN, HUGO J.",
      "adminPdProfilePersonId": 12626582,
      "pdNameList": "ZOU, SIGE",
      "adminSroProfilePersonId": 1947587,
      "sroNameList": "KELLY, ANDREA B",
      "adminGmoProfilePersonId": 2110593,
      "gmoNameList": "WIGGINS, JENELLE D.",
      "adminGmsProfilePersonId": 9490784,
      "gmsNameList": "FLEMING, CHRISTINA"
    }
  ],
  "competingApplsFiscalData": [
    {
      "year": "2016",
      "isFunded": 218,
      "notFunded": 0
    },
    {
      "year": "2015",
      "isFunded": 60,
       "notFunded": 0
    },
    {
      "year": "2014",
      "isFunded": 13,
      "notFunded": 0
    },
    {
      "year": "2013",
      "isFunded": 5,
      "notFunded": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

When I plug this into the website at:
http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ it says it is valid.

But when I plug it into the AnyPoint API Designer by MuleSoft it says:
"Example does not conform to the schema:Content is not valid accoding to schema: Expected type object but found type string object, string"

And then further down it says:
"JS-YAML: expected a single document in the stream but found more".

Why is it  saying this?

Comment: getting the same error, did you resolve it

Comment: I think I may know the problem (as I just had this issues myself).  The reading of the JSON to be validated was going into a JArray, which did not take the entire file, only the first portion.  The Jarray would magically close it and validate just that.